# Outlook 07/13 Alignment Issue

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have a responsive email (email css inlined) whereby I have 2 columns and the text in the 2nd column is not aligning center to the icons. Suggestions?

This only seems to be happening in Outlook 07 & 2013. Looks fine in other browsers and email clients when run through Litmus

```html
<!-- Invite Information with icons -->
          <table class="outer" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 600px; padding: 0;">
            <tr align="center" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;">
              <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
                  <table class="container" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 508px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                      <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                        <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                              <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 508px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                  <td class="text-pad" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <table class="full-table" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; padding: 0;">
                                      <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                        <td width="65" class="icon" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                          <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{24ee00f3-6d64-4acd-8b11-6458bd6a03c9}_icn-calendar.png" alt="" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;" align="left">
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="middle" class="text-pad-left icon-text" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" align="left">
                                          <h5 elq-edit="true" class='eloqua-editable-content' style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Arial Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 22px; margin: 15px 0 0; padding: 0;" align="left">Friday, 11<sup>th</sup> - 13<sup>th</sup> September 2015</h5>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                        <td width="65" class="icon" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                          <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{e02be391-bab6-4cf4-84a2-9ff6ca979b58}_icn-clock.png" alt="" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;" align="left">
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="middle" class="text-pad-left icon-text" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" align="left">
                                          <h5 elq-edit="true" class='eloqua-editable-content' style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Arial Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 22px; margin: 15px 0 0; padding: 0;" align="left">7.00pm - Welcome Party</h5>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                        <td width="65" class="icon" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                          <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{3a92ceeb-920c-48c8-b125-8877d00fcbe6}_icn-location-marker.png" alt="" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;" align="left">
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="middle" class="text-pad-left icon-text" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" align="left">
                                          <h5 elq-edit="true" class='eloqua-editable-content' style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Arial Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 22px; margin: 15px 0 0; padding: 0;" align="left">Evian Resort Hotel</h5>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- END Invite Information with icons -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Zurb's Ink framework. I was able to utilize, with a few mods, the sub-columns / sub-grid features.

```html
<!-- Invite Information with icons -->
          <table class="outer" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 600px; padding: 0;">
            <tr align="center" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;">
              <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
                  <table class="container" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 508px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                      <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">

                        <!-- Start Row -->
                        <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">

                              <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 508px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">

                                  <td class="two sub-columns center" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; min-width: 0px; width: 16.666666%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <center style="min-width: 65px; width: 100%;">
                                      <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{24ee00f3-6d64-4acd-8b11-6458bd6a03c9}_icn-calendar.png" alt="" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;" align="center">
                                    </center>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="ten sub-columns" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; text-align: left; min-width: 0px; width: 83.333333%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="left">
                                    <h5 elq-edit="true" style="font-size: 22px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Arial Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left">Friday, 11<sup>th</sup> - 13<sup>th</sup> September 2015</h5>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END row -->

                        <!-- Start Row -->
                        <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                              <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 508px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">

                                  <td class="two sub-columns center" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; min-width: 0px; width: 16.666666%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <center style="min-width: 65px; width: 100%;">
                                      <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{e02be391-bab6-4cf4-84a2-9ff6ca979b58}_icn-clock.png" alt="" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;" align="center">
                                    </center>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="ten sub-columns" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; text-align: left; min-width: 0px; width: 83.333333%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="left">
                                    <h5 elq-edit="true" style="font-size: 22px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Arial Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left">7.00pm - Welcome Party</h5>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END row -->

                        <!-- Start Row -->
                        <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                              <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 508px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">

                                  <td class="two sub-columns center" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; min-width: 0px; width: 16.666666%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <center style="min-width: 65px; width: 100%;">
                                      <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{3a92ceeb-920c-48c8-b125-8877d00fcbe6}_icn-location-marker.png" alt="" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: left; clear: both; display: block;" align="center">
                                    </center>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="ten sub-columns" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; text-align: left; min-width: 0px; width: 83.333333%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;" align="left">
                                    <h5 elq-edit="true" style="font-size: 22px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Arial Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left">Evian Resort Hotel</h5>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END row -->

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- END Invite Information with icons -->
```